# App showing only direction and distance of goal

Tags: ios, iphone-app

I used to have a GPS device that tells me the distance and direction (like a compass not showing north but to the goal) of a set of coordinates. It's broken so I can't use it for GeoCaching.

Is there any app for iPhone that does *just* this? I don't want mapping features, because that makes it too easy in my eyes.

It would be good if the app is relatively cheap or free of cost. I've found [this app](https://appsto.re/de/6asBE.i) but it has no rating and costs >1$ so I'm reluctant to give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

There's a free app located here:
[Free GPS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/free-gps/id335392176?mt=8) which appears to address your objective.

[image: FreeGPS screenshot]

If this doesn't work for you, consider to search using terms such as "marine," "boating," "aviation," "aircraft." All of these types remove the road following requirement of many GPS programs.

Comment: +1: Thank you for your tipps and suggestions. For the reasons listed in my self-answer, I decided to go with the other app.

Answer (score 0):

After comparing the [Geocashing Compass](https://itunes.apple.com/de/app/geocaching-compass/id510468154?l=en&mt=8) and Free GPS suggestion I decided to go with the first because

- It doesn't have ads
- The design is better
- It is more accurate than the free app
- It only costs very little